# Regular expression to remove specific characters in email addresses

Tags: java, regex

Im trying to figure out how i can remove certain characters in an email address before the domain name using nothing but a simple regex and `replaceAll` in Java.

In email addresses,

- Need to remove any number of `.` before `@<domain name>`
- Also remove anything between `+` up to `@` but not including `@`. For instance in `joebloggs+123@domain.com` should be `joebloggs@domain.com`.

So far I have,

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String matchingRegex = "(\\.|(\\+.*(?=@)))";
    System.out.println("joe.bloggs+123@gmail.com".replaceAll(matchingRegex, ""));
  }
}
```

which replaces everything including the domain name.
`joebloggs@gmailcom`

What i really need is `joebloggs@gmail.com`.
Can this be achieved with regex alone ?

Comment: That's because the beginning of your regex accounts for *all* periods: `\\.|otherStuff` is saying "Periods OR other stuff". Since periods *after* the @ fit the regex (due to that first statement of `\\.` followed by a `|`), they're also being removed.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Anyway to fix it with the look ahead ?

Comment: Escaped `+` to handle `+123` with that look ahead

Comment: Oh, my bad, didn't see it in the test string at first. Still, your regex says "Periods OR a + followed by *any character* behind a @". That first expression, the `\\.` followed by a pipe, is what's causing all your periods to be replaced.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Yup definitely. Is there anyway for that first part to say search up to `@` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another look ahead did the trick in the end.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String matchingRegex = "((\\.+)(?=.*@)|(\\+.*(?=@)))";
    System.out.println("joe.bloggs+123@gmail.com".replaceAll(matchingRegex, ""));
    System.out.println("joebloggs+123@gmail.com".replaceAll(matchingRegex, ""));
    System.out.println("joe.bloggs@gmail.com".replaceAll(matchingRegex, ""));
    System.out.println("joe.bloggs.123@gmail.com".replaceAll(matchingRegex, ""));
    System.out.println("joe.bloggs.123+456@gmail.com".replaceAll(matchingRegex, ""));
    System.out.println("joebloggs@gmail.com".replaceAll(matchingRegex, ""));
    System.out.println("joe.bloggs.123+456.789@gmail.com".replaceAll(matchingRegex, ""));
  }
}
```

Results in,

```
joebloggs@gmail.com
joebloggs@gmail.com
joebloggs@gmail.com
joebloggs123@gmail.com
joebloggs123@gmail.com
joebloggs@gmail.com
joebloggs123@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try spliting the string (the email) on the @ and running replaceAll on the the first half and then put the strings back together.

Check out: [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

For splitting strings.

Comment: Or he could fix his regex. Although this is answer may work, it creates overhead which could easily be avoided if using the proper regular expression.

Comment: Splitting would be easy but like i said it should be a regex and `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex `[.](?=.*@)|(?=\\+)(.*)(?=@)`. It looks up dots up to @ (even if there's text in between), or everything from + up to @. Hope it helps https://regex101.com/r/gyUpta/1

```
class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    String matchingRegex = "[.](?=.*@)|(?=\\+)(.*)(?=@)";
    System.out.println("joe.bloggs+123@gmail.com".replaceAll(matchingRegex, ""));
 }
}
```

Comment: Nice. thats also another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick...

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
       String matchingRegex = "(\\.|(\\+.*(?=@)))";
       String email = "joe.bloggs+123@gmail.com";
       String user = email.substring(0, email.indexOf("@")+1);
       String domain = email.substring(email.indexOf("@")+1);          
       System.out.println(user.replaceAll(matchingRegex, "") + domain);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way I have found to do it.

```java
      String address = "joe.bloggs+123@gmail.com";
      int at = address.indexOf("@");

      address = address.substring(0, at).replaceAll("\\.|\\+.*", "")
            + address.substring(at);

      System.out.println(address);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you try to split for regex sorry i don't remember java this example is in javascript

```
let string = "joe.bloggs+123@gmail.com"

//firts the function
function splitString(params) {
    return params.split(/\+(.)+\@/)
}

//second the concat
let list = splitString(string)
//     the first element+the las element 
console.log(`${list[0]}${list[list.length -1]}`)
```